# olapR query returns null object

Tags: r, olap-cube, microsoft-r

I have been using olapR (along with Microsoft R Client, which you need in order to use olapR) to do MDX queries on a MSOLAP database.

However, every time I execute any query it return a null object. I know these are not empty queries. Here is an example:

```
library(olapR)

cnnstr="Provider=MSOLAP;Password=***;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=***;Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***"

olapCnn=OlapConnection(cnnstr)

qry <- Query(validate = TRUE)

cube(qry) <- "PER - Prestación Servicios de Salud"
columns(qry) <- c("[Measures].[Número Personas Atendidas]")
rows(qry) <- c("[Diagnóstico Principal].[Diagnósticos].[Diagnósticos].MEMBERS") 

results1=executeMD(olapCnn, qry)
```

The problem is results1 is NULL.

If I use the command execute2D instead I get the following error:
Unknown object recieved from olapRExecuteRecordset, which is just a consequence of the object being return being NULL

Answer (score 0):

Since the author has not answered here, I can tell how I solved this in case someone else has maybe the same issue.

Basically I'm using 2-3 cubes, but I had only used the connection string to one of the cubes, so when I tried to query the other cubes I got the NULL object, or unknown object received. The solution in my case was simply to create different connection strings for each of the cubes, and use the correct connection string when querying.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Maybe give an example? Thanks!

Comment: Look at authors "cnnstr". This was were my fault was. I forgot to specify the correct "Initial catalog" and "Cube" for the cube I was querying to, because I was working with other cubes as well. When I used the correct information for the intended cube, all worked. Hope I could be of help! (official documentation for connection string here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/connection-string-properties-analysis-services)